# VBA calculate individual hours, from list of multiple employees

Tags: vba, excel

I tried to avoid using VBA for this due to my lack of familiarity, but it looks like this is complex enough to require the Excel native language.

What I have is a CSV with a list of employees hours worked each day, all in separate rows. Employee name, Date, Regular Hours, and OT Hours are in separate columns. The challenge is that for employee Bob, there may be 20 rows for one day. Bob applies a slice of time to different projects all day. Then of course there are multiple days and multiple employees. What I am trying to end up with is a report that shows all of the regular and OT hours (separately) for each employee on a daily basis. 
What I can't wrap my head around is how to start the compilation. I am guessing that separating each employee would be the start. Then separating each date, then adding all hours for that date. 
I appreciate any assistance.

```
Emp#    Name    Date        Reg     OT
Emp1    Bob     1/1/2016    8.00    0.00
Emp1    Bob     1/4/2016    3.00    0.00
Emp1    Bob     1/4/2016    5.00    0.00
Emp1    Bob     1/5/2016    2.00    0.00
Emp1    Bob     1/5/2016    1.00    0.00
Emp1    Bob     1/5/2016    5.00    0.00
Emp1    Bob     1/6/2016    1.00    0.00
Emp1    Bob     1/6/2016    2.00    0.00
Emp1    Bob     1/6/2016    5.00    0.00
Emp1    Bob     1/7/2016    2.00    0.00
Emp2    Henry   1/1/2016    8.00    0.00
Emp2    Henry   1/4/2016    8.00    0.00
Emp2    Henry   1/5/2016    8.00    0.00
Emp2    Henry   1/6/2016    2.00    0.00
Emp2    Henry   1/6/2016    6.00    0.00
Emp2    Henry   1/7/2016    1.50    0.00
Emp2    Henry   1/7/2016    0.50    0.00
Emp2    Henry   1/7/2016    6.00    0.00
Emp2    Henry   1/8/2016    8.00    0.00
Emp2    Henry   1/11/2016   8.00    0.00
Emp2    Henry   1/12/2016   3.00    0.00
Emp2    Henry   1/12/2016   1.00    0.00
Emp2    Henry   1/12/2016   3.00    0.00
Emp2    Henry   1/12/2016   1.00    0.00
Emp2    Henry   1/13/2016   1.50    0.00
```

Comment: Or you can use SUMIFS

Comment: I looked at SUMIFS and either it would not do the job or I did not know how to get it to do the job.

Comment: Show some data and the formula you tried and we may be able to help.

Comment: is it safe to assume that every employees name is unique? you sont have two different John smiths working for the company?  Or you have a unique employee code in there somewhere?

Comment: you should be able to do this in Excel without the need for VBA as well.

Comment: All employee names are unique. If I can make this happen in Excel, without VBA, that would be better for me, but at this point anything that gets me started on the first separation (names) would be great.

Comment: Sounds like a pivot table.

Comment: Unfortunately, it sounds like a lot of things. That is part of the problem. The starting point. As for adding code, I don't have any yet. Attempting to add some sample data.

Answer (score 4):

Your description sounds like you want to use a pivot table. They are easy to build - this example literally took me 5 minutes to build, including typing in the data.

As an illustration, you can take data that looks like this ...

[image]

and consolidate it in a way that provides a lot of flexibility in looking at it. Such as this:

[image]

or this

[image]

There are several good, simple tutorials available on building Pivot Tables. A google search turns up plenty.

Comment: Looks pretty good. I will try this path and see how it works.

Comment: @bubblesTheturtle - after looking into it, it is good practice on SO to mark the answer that answered your question by clicking the check mark next to it. Thanks.

Comment: I understand, but let me try it before I get too excited. Thank you for taking the time. I will work on this tomorrow and report back so that future visitors know what worked.

Comment: Yep, that about does it. Thanks for all the responses.